# Date Formatter Google Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, nsdateformatter

what is the date formatter google appengine?
i'm using this but it does not work

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

Comment: are you talking about the formatter used by cloud endpoints?

Comment: no, but cloud datastore format

Answer (score 1):

In Go, when you run something like `time.Now().String()` you get a result that looks something like this:

`2015-08-03 02:17:53.083373704 +0000 UTC`

To get it to play nicely with `NSDateFormatter` you'll need to remove the spaces and then sanitize the timezone input. `NSDateFormatter` accepts four different time zone formats (represented by one through four different z's) which you can find laid out in the [unicode standards.](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) Unfortunately, Go doesn't conform to one of these standards so you have to remove the timezone represented in characters. *By default, App Engine defaults to UTC time. If you have overridden this, you will have to remove the timezone you set.* This works nicely because Apple defaults to UTC as well.

Anyways, the code should look like this:

```
NSString *timeZoneCode = @"UTC"; // Change here if you have overridden it

NSString *dateNoSpaces = [dateStringstringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSString *dateNoTimeZoneCode = [dateNoSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:timeZoneCode withString:@""];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSZZZ"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateNoTimeZoneCode];
```

Comment: @mikejobs Want to mark this as correct if it worked?